# Enhanced Health Overview not reporting properly for Multi-container Docker configuration in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, cloud, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I uploaded a project having `multi-containers docker platform` with two containers say `xyz` and `abc` in `aws elastic-beanstalk`. `xyz` contains tomcat server in it. I have following configuration in my project for `Dockerrunner.aws.json` file.

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "xyz",
      "image": "<PLACEHOLDER_REPLACED_BY_CICD_TOOLS>",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 2048,
      "links": [
        "abc"
      ],
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "ENVIRONMENT",
          "value": "QA"
        },
        {
          "name": "LOG_HOME",
          "value": "/usr/local/tomcat/logs"
        },
        .
        .
        .
      ],
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "awseb-logs-xyz",
          "containerPath": "/usr/local/tomcat/logs"
        }
      ],
      .
      .
    },
    {
      "name": "abc",
      "image": "image123",
      "essential": true,
      .
      .
      .
    }
  ]
}
```

But, I am not able to view data in health section of elastic-beanstalk.
[image]

What I did so far to resolve this issue:

- I read (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/health-enhanced-serverlogs.html) and got to know that elastic beanstalk has special logging format for multi-container health page to work.
- For testing propose, I manually created an error log-file in the same format by accessing ec2 instance. The file I created in ec2 instance host at location `/var/log/containers/xyz` (where health-agent read logs) was also mapped properly to tomcat's log file's location (i.e. `/usr/local/tomcat/logs`) in `xyz` docker container.

But, I still could not see changes in enhanced health overview section.

Comment: What data are you expecting to see in the health section that you don't see there now?

Comment: @kichik, as shown in above figure, there are some "--" in Requests and Latency sections, which should be filled up with data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this AWS support site](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/request-latency-enhanced-health/):

> From the [Elastic Beanstalk console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/), verify that enhanced health reporting is enabled:
>
> 1. Choose **Configuration**, and then on the **Health** panel under **Web Tier**, choose the edit gear.
> 2. Under **Health Reporting**, ensure the **System type** is set to **Enhanced**.
>
> **64-bit Amazon Linux 2016.xx vx.x.x running Node.js platform:**
>
> Ensure that the correct proxy server is configured:
>
> 1. Choose **Configuration**, and then on the **Software Configuration** panel under **Web Tier**, choose the edit gear.
> 2. In **Container Options**, ensure you have a **Proxy server** selected.
>      If Proxy server is set to **none**, the application log file is not generated under `/var/log/nginx/healthd/` and health reporting does not generate data to display.
>
> You can also modify the Node.js logs and location to be compatible with enhanced health log format, then review the `healthd` configuration file `/etc/healthd/config.yaml`.
>
> **64-bit Amazon Linux 2016.xx vx.x.x running Multicontainer Docker 2.xx.x:**
>
> This platform doesn’t come with a proxy server, so you need to ensure that logs are produced in the correct format from their containers and configure `healthd` to read them. To use enhanced health monitoring in Multicontainer Docker environments, you need to configure `healthd` to consume these logs.
>
> To provide logs to the health agent, ensure the following:
>
> - Logs are in the correct format
> - Logs are written to `/var/log/nginx/healthd/`
> - Log names use the format: `application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour`
> - Logs are rotated once per hour
> - Logs are not truncated
>
> **Note**: With the Node.js platform, if you disable the proxy, the logs are not created under `/var/logs/nginx/healthd/`. You must either re-enable the proxy or configure your Node.js application to produce logs under `/var/logs/nginx/healthd/`
>
> This sample [Docker-multicontainer-v2.zip](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/samples/docker-multicontainer-v2.zip) code shows how to manage ebextensions where the `healthd` configuration is set to read another directory. [...]

I think this part might be able to help you:

> If you are unable to see information for a server in the Enhanced Health Overview, check the `healthd` service status on the instance and ensure that it’s running. If it is not running, restart the service.
>
> This sample code shows how to check the healthd service status:
>
> `$ ps aux | grep healthd`
>
> This sample code shows how to restart the `healthd` service:
>
> `[ec2-user@ip-172-31-39-182 ~]$ sudo initctl restart healthd`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [@char's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55589535/399632), specifically for multicontainer docker environments, you need to [mount the log location](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_v2config.html#create_deploy_docker_v2config_dockerrun_format) and EB will take care of the rest automatically:

> Elastic Beanstalk creates log volumes on the container instance, one
>   for each Docker container, at /var/log/containers/containername. These
>   volumes are named awseb-logs-containername and should be mounted to
>   the location within the container file structure where logs are
>   written.

This is what is the multi-container docker example:

```
{
  "name": "nginx-proxy",
  "image": "nginx:alpine",
  "essential": true,
  "memoryReservation": 8,
  "mountPoints": [{
    "sourceVolume": "awseb-logs-nginx-proxy",
    "containerPath": "/var/log/nginx"
  }],
  "portMappings": [{
    "hostPort": 80,
    "containerPort": 80
  }]
}
```

The key being the `mountPoint` `awseb-logs-nginx-proxy` which is `awseb-logs-<container_name>`.

This is in correctly documented in the OP's config, but it was the piece I was missing which is part of the total answer.